# fscanf only reading first field C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm doing an assignment where I have to create a grade report program. Everything was working, but the final section has me altering the code so it reads data from a file (student.dat) and uses that as data for the output.

Sample of student.dat (there are 100 lines similar to these in total).

```
Julius Hoffman,95,92,79,90,90
Dianne Conner,100,100,80,90,85
Mitchell Cooper,100,95,89,85,95
```

My issue is with the fscanf command as it is only reading the first name

Sample Output (the final program will have 100 lines total)

```
Please enter a filename: student.dat
Student Name      W(30%)   Q(15%)   T(20%)   P(15%)   E(20%)   TOTAL(100%) GRADE

Julius Hoffman    0        0        0        0        0         0.00         F              
                  0        0        0        0        0         0.00         F              
                  0        0        0        0        0         0.00         F
```

The function that handles the file reading is below.

```
int read(char filename[], char name[][MAX_NAME_SIZE], float w[], float q[], float t[],float p[],float e[]){

    int i =0;

    FILE *fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp != NULL) {

            for(i=0; i < MAX_CLASS_SIZE; i++){

                    fscanf(fp, "%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]", name[i], w[i], q[i], t[i], p[i], e[i]);

            }
            fclose(fp);
    } else {
            printf("Failed to open file\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And just in case, this is the function that handles presenting the report to the user

```
void display( char name[][MAX_NAME_SIZE], float w[], float q[], float t[], float p[], float e[], float total[], char grade[][MAX_LETTER_SIZE] ) {

    int i = 0;

    printf("Student Name      W(30%)   Q(15%)   T(20%)   P(15%)   E(20%)   TOTAL(100%)   GRADE\n===================================================================================\n");

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_CLASS_SIZE; i++){
            printf("%-15s   %-3.0f      %-3.0f      %-3.0f      %-3.0f      %-3.0f       %-3.2f         %-15s\n", name[i], w[i], q[i], t[i], p[i], e[i], total[i], grade[i]);
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Also, scanf needs the address of the location to put the value, so for w, q, etc., you need to pass in address of array location, e.g. `fscanf(fp, "%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]", name[i], &w[i], &q[i], &t[i], &p[i], &e[i]);`

Comment: @Edgar Rokyan, I'm pretty sure it also matters for arrays.....

Comment: `"%[^,]"` expect to save results in a character array, not a `float[]`.

Comment: @DBug Ohm, my bad, of course you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fscanf` should look like this:

`fscanf(fp, " %[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", name[i], &w[i], &q[i], &t[i], &p[i], &e[i]);`

Notes:

- `%[^,]` control format is only for reading characters until the comma. There is no reason why you use that control format for *all* your data (which include several `int` afterwards I suppose).
- You should also check the return results of your `fscanf`, make sure that it returns the correct value, in this case you are reading 6 values from your text file at a time.

Comment: I had to change the "%d's" to "%f's". But it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: `"%[^,],%f,%f,%f,%f,%f"` will make the second name begin with a `'\n'`

Comment: @chux - cool, I added the space in control string to remove `\n`.

Comment: @Alovrick - please an additional space in the control format as I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mis-match `scanf()` format specifier. Use `"%f"` with  `float *`

Also save debug time.  Simply read the line into a buffer and then scan it.

`" %n"` scans white-space and then save the index of the scan into `n`.  So if `n > 0`, code knows the entire line scanned.  if `buf[n]`, the scan did not finish at the end of the line.

```
for(i=0; i < MAX_CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
  char buf[200];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) == NULL) break;

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, fp, " %[^,],%f ,%f ,%f ,%f ,%f %n", 
    name[i], &w[i], &q[i], &t[i], &p[i], &e[i], &n);
  if (n > 0) break; // format error
  if (buf[n]) break; // extra text

  // Use name[i], w[i], q[i], t[i], p[i], e[i]
}
```